# Parsing pyspark Row stored as string

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataset that contains some nested pyspark rows stored as strings. When I read them into pyspark, of the columns is read as a string that look something like this:

```
'Row(name='Bob', updated='Sat Nov 21 12:57:54', isProgrammer=True)'
```

My goal is to parse some of these subfields into separate columns, but I am having trouble reading them in. .

```
df.select(col('user')['name'].alias('name'))
```

is the syntax I am trying, but it doesn't seem to be working. It gives me this error:

```
Can't extract value from user#11354: need struct type but got string
```

Is there an easy way to read this type of data?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you can't change the input you get the code below runs a udf the eval the Row and then takes all columns into an array of strings.
You can tinker with the udf to make it return as a MapType or a StructType.

I would highly recommend changing the input though from this format.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
def custom_parser_udf(unparsed_row):
  from pyspark.sql import Row
  
  as_row = eval(unparsed_row)
  return [str(as_row.name), str(as_row.updated), str(as_row.isProgrammer)]
```

and then you can run it in a function to get whatever you need.

```
result = df.withColumn("parsed_date", custom_parser_udf("unparsed_col"))
```

an alternative is to run some sort of parser based on `split` function which also, I can't recommend .